# Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionDetailsItem", for: indexPath) as? CharacterCollectionDetailsTableCell else {
        fatalError("Dequeued cell is not an instance of CharacterDetailsTableViewCell class.")
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionDetailsItem", for: indexPath) as? CharacterCollectionDetailsTableCell else {
        fatalError("Dequeued cell is not an instance of CharacterDetailsTableViewCell class.")
    }
    if let character = character {
        cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataType: dataTypes[indexPath.row], characterEntity: character)
    }
}
```

I'm really don't understand why this error happens, could someone please help me what I do wrong?

Comment: This is weird, You already getting cell in willDisplay method, thereafter your are dequeueReusableCell it. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting error because of the wrong implementation of the data source and delegate methods of the `tableview`. `dequeueReusableCell` is used for creating reusable cells in the `tableview`. Hence it should be implemented in the `cellForRow` dataSource method of the tableview. You are doing it fine in the first method but this is where you are doing it wrong.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionDetailsItem", for: indexPath) as? CharacterCollectionDetailsTableCell else {
        fatalError("Dequeued cell is not an instance of CharacterDetailsTableViewCell class.")
    }
    if let character = character {
        cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataType: dataTypes[indexPath.row], characterEntity: character)
    }
}
```

This method is not where you can create cell instead you can perform various tasks based on the requirement when the cell will be displayed. So based on what you have asked it could be like this..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionDetailsItem", for: indexPath) as? CharacterCollectionDetailsTableCell else {
        fatalError("Dequeued cell is not an instance of CharacterDetailsTableViewCell class.")
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = cell as? CharacterCollectionDetailsTableCell {
        guard let character = character else {
            return
        }
        cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataType: dataTypes[indexPath.row], characterEntity: character)
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, it was my carelessness.

Answer (score 1):

The error is being caused by your misuse of `dequeueReusableCell` in `willDisplayCell`. You must only ever use that in `cellForRowAt`.

Besides, the cell is already given to you as a parameter to `willDisplayCell`.

Update to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let character = character {
        let myCell = cell as! CharacterCollectionDetailsTableCell
        myCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataType: dataTypes[indexPath.row], characterEntity: character)
    }
}
```

And simply force-cast the cell type. If you setup your code incorrectly, it will crash just as well as using `guard` and `fatalError`.